# What is Java Byte Array and How should it be used?

Tags: java

What does it mean by byte array ? I mean it holds the 0s and 1s just like how data is hold in memory ?

For example

```
String a = "32";
byte [] arr = a.getBytes() ;
```

What does exist now inside arr array,why and when to use it?

Comment: Did you try to google it?

Comment: @TDG I tried to google it and ended up at this question...

Comment: @SpencerStewart Well, this is a very basic topic, should be mentioned in any decent tutorial, even 4 years ago, when the question was asked. But I guess that now, due to the high popularity of this site you found this (bad) question.

Comment: @TDG There are many questions on this site that are basic programming 101 type questions. The question itself wasn't bad, it definitely could have been worded better and needs some punctuation and grammar corrections. I may be wrong but the question fits in fine with this site. We're striving to be a definitive wiki-like resource for programming questions. 

I googled for byte array because I wasn't sure if there was anything special about it other than being a literal array with byte values inside of it. Evan Williams' answer was perfect and what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 10):

By byte array, it literally means an array where each item is of the `byte` primitive data type. If you do not know the difference between a `byte` and a common `int` (Integer), the main difference is the bit width: bytes are 8-bit and integers are 32-bit. You can read up on that [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=260).

If you do not know what an array is, an array is basically a sequence of items (in your case a sequence of bytes, declared as `byte[]`).

The function `a.getBytes()` takes `a`, which is a String, and returns an array of bytes. This can be done because the human-readable characters in a String can be represented as 8-bit numbers, where the mapping between number and character is determined by the [CharSet](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/). Examples of two common CharSets are [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) and [UTF-8](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_basic_latin.asp). Now, `arr` is an array of bytes, where each byte in the array represents each character in the original string `a`. In both ASCII and UTF-8, the String `"32"` is represented by the bytes `51` and `50` in decimal, and `0x33` and `0x32` in hexadecimal.

Byte arrays are commonly used in applications that read and write data byte-wise, such as socket connections that send data in byte streams through TCP or UDP protocols.

Hope I could help!

Comment: @krl can you select my answer as the correct one? thanks